# char *argv - float/int numbers

Tags: scanf, argv

I am getting the numbers from `argv[1]` and should distinguish between `floating` and `int` numbers. 
So I decided to do it with `sscanf`.

Trying to convert the `string` into `float` - I failed.
(if it is an `int` value, it shouldn't be included in the output.)

Part of the Code:

```
  float check;
  sscanf(argv[1], "%f", &check) == 1);
  if(check == 1){
     printf("is a float");
  }
```

The issue is, that `sscanf` returns 1 even if it is an `int` value. How can I stop `sscanf` from returning 1, if it is an `int` value? I also tried it with `strtod`, failed again. Any ideas, what am I doing wrong?

Best regards,

Keita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Int values are float values, so if you want to distinguish between float values that are also ints and floats that are not ints, you need to try it as an int first.  In addition, scanf, will return success if any prefix matches the specifier and will ignore extra stuff on the end of the string.  If you don't want that, you need to use %n and make sure it has consumed the whole string.  So you end up with:

```
float checkf;
int checki, len;
if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d %n", &checki, &len) >= 1 && argv[1][len] == 0) {
    printf("%s is an int\n", argv[i]);
} else if (sscanf(argv[i], "%f %n", &checkf, &len) >= 1 && argv[i][len] == 0) {
    printf("%s is a float\n", argv[i]);
} else {
    printf("%s is neither an int nor a float\n", argv[i]);
}
```

`%n` in the format string causes scanf to report how many chars of input have been consumed up to that point in the format -- putting it at the end of the format allows us to check that the end of the format matches the end of the string and there's not other cruft present in the input.  In this case a float input like `2.5` looks like an integer `2` followed by the extra string `.5` to the first scanf call, so the scanf will succeed (return 1), but len will be set to the offet of the `.` (so `argv[i][len]` will be `'.'`, not 0)

Comment: Thanks its working -.) - do you know a library function except sscanf for distinguishing between float and int?

Comment: You can use `strtol` and `strtod` to do largely the same thing in the same way.

Comment: alright, can you also explain why you have used argv[1][len] == 0 ? Are you comparing the length of both numbers?

Comment: I'm checking that the format consumed the entire string and there's no extra junk in the argument (so the end of the format corresponds to the nul terminator in the string.)  There's a space before the %n so it will allow extra whitespace after the number -- you could remove that if you want to disallow trailing spaces.